# Vue 2.7 getCurrentInstance() trying to get properties like $vuetify

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to migrate from vuetify 2.6 to 2.7 because of composition-api but I'm getting a lot of errors when trying to get properties of the Vue instance, for example I'm using vue with Vuetify and I have a separed "helper" to try to get the $vuetify instance but everytime I'm getting `undefined` even when I'm trying to get the property from a setup() in the App.vue I get undefined, same thing happened when trying to get the $route property of `vue-router` from the instance with `getCurrentInstance()` then only solution I had with the router was using an internal composable of `vue-router/composables` to get the route.

Another thing that also happens is that the `getCurrentInstance()` sometimes returns null.

My main.js looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
...

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

./plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  preset
  ...
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default{
  setup(){
    console.log( getCurrentInstance().proxy, getCurrentInstance().proxy.$vuetify )
    // returns: {}, undefined
    // sometimes returns null, undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

versions:

```
"vue": "^2.7.11"
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.8"
"vuetify": "^2.6.11"
```

Anyone knows what it could be?, Thanks.

Comment: to be fair, there is no migration required from 2.6 to 2.7 - however if you want to adopt the new composition-api then, yes, that's what you have to refactor in your code - oddly, the code you posted has no reference to `$vuetify` nor `getCurrentInstance` so, not sure if this is the code you want help with

Comment: I've added an example of what I get in the App.vue.

Comment: what if you do the same thing in `onMounted` in App.vue?

Comment: `getCurrentInstance` is not a public (documented) function, I'm not sure this supose to work. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12596#issuecomment-1173269807

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe that would work, but the thing is that why can’t I get it on window load?…

Comment: I don't know, I was just asking what happens

Comment: @S.Visser Yes, is not in Vue3, but I was getting the right value with the vue composition api on Vue 2.6…

Comment: if within App.vue or other component can't you just use `this.$vuetify` as [documented](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#application-service)?  Within a utility helper you could try [this suggestion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3760#issuecomment-1178468293)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: Can't reproduce in vue v2.7.12. I tried vue v2.7.11 and can reproduce your issue. There is a severe regression in v2.7.11, please upgrade your vue.

Here is a minimal example of v2.7.12.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fjpdck

`getCurrentInstance().proxy` does return a `VueComponent` and `getCurrentInstance().proxy.$vuetify` gets the vuetify instance successfully.

By the way, the recommended way to get `$route` instance in `setup` is

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router/composables'  // need vue-router v3.6
export default{
  setup(){
    const route = useRoute()
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, for some reason it works well now even in Vue 2.7.13 :D